# Multiple nodes per task SLURM

Tags: parallel-processing, slurm

I would like to run one job that requires more CPUs than those available in one node. The maximum is 96 CPUs, then when I write `srun -c 200 python my_script.py` i get: `srun: error: Unable to allocate resources: Requested node configuration is not available` is there a way to tell SLURM that I want to use different nodes for the same task? Or I cannot do that, and I should split the tasks?

Comment: With `-c 200` you are asking for 200 cpus per task. But a task can only run in a single node and you have up to 96 cpus there, so you should use more than one task in more than one node to be able to use more than 96 cpus. This means that your code must be able to run in parallel using mutiple nodes (usually using MPI as its message passing interface). The other option is to split your workload in multiple independent tasks and run them separately with less CPUs each of them.

Comment: That answers my question. I cannot assign a task more CPUs than the CPUs in a node. I actually use mpi4py to split the work in several sub-tasks, but I only know how to split the work in CPUs with scatter and gather. Not how to share them between nodes. I guess I'll go for your second suggestion. In any case, If you want to write your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: The scatter-gather approach is one of the usual when doing MPI parallelism. It is just that instead of setting an array and giving it to a subtask, you have to send that array to the subtask (by a message, a shared resource, a socket...). The approach does not chenge, only how you implement it.

Comment: Either case, you question is not a programming question, so it should not be here and it does not deserve an answer. Anyways, happy to help! :-)